# CMake warning on ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unable to get rid of include directory warnings during a catkin_make.

One of my packages is dependent on boost. I made sure to use find_package so that the include dirs variables get populated, but still get warnings during a build...although boost is discovered during the build. See warning at the end of the post.
Thanks.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test)

# search for everything we need to build the package
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

# since we need boost search it as well
# find_package makes the ${..._INCLUDE_DIRS} ${..._LIBRARIES} variables we use later
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

# export the dependencis of this package for who ever depends on us
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs 
  DEPENDS boost
)

# tell catkin where to find the headers for this project
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# make the executables
add_executable( test_node src/test.cpp )

add_dependencies( test_node   ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} )

target_link_libraries( test_node  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Warning:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'test'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(test)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'boost' but neither 'boost_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor
  'boost_LIBRARIES' is defined.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251005/cmake-warning-on-$%7Bboost_include_dirs%7D/) by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2016-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `DEPENDS Boost` (capitalized)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluehash](https://answers.ros.org/users/26693/bluehash/) on 2017-01-03**:
Thanks. That was it.